# Is it right to use extern keyword in "extern int x" in both header and source for a global variable?

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

There is one variable called `BOT_TIME` that varies with the difficulty of my game, and hence isn't `const`. There are many files that use it. I intend to use it as a global variable.

**1)** In `constants.h` I declare it `extern int BOT_TIME`.
In `constants.cpp`, I declare it `extern int BOT_TIME`.

BUILD => undefined references to the variable in all sources(Yes, I've included the header).

**2)** In `constants.h` I declare it `int BOT_TIME`.
In `constants.cpp`, I declare it `int BOT_TIME`.
Since `non-consts` are by default `extern` , I decided to leave that keyword.

BUILD => Multiple definition of the variable (shows in each source file that has constants.h included)

**3)** In `constants.h` I declare it `extern int BOT_TIME`.
In `constants.cpp`, I declare it `int BOT_TIME`.

This works.

Where is the issue?

Initializing the variable to something in `constants.cpp` makes it work for cases 1 and 3.

What is this happening?
Which is the right approach?

Comment: Using `extern` makes it a *declaration*, but not a *definition*. I.e. `extern` says "it exists somewhere, but not here". So you need exactly one place *without* `extern`.

Comment: What exactly does it mean when people say "a non-const variable is extern by default" ? How does one show that omitting `extern` will still keep it `extern`? Isn't that what default means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a variable as many times as you want, you can and have to define it only once.

```
extern int BOT_TIME;
```

is a declaration.

```
int BOT_TIME;
```

is a definition.

The definition has to appear in a single implementation file.

> Since non-consts are by default extern , I decided to leave that keyword.

Nope. How'd you figure?

To answer the questions:

1) There's no definition, only declarations.

2) The assumption is wrong. You define the symbol multiple times.

3) It works because that's the correct way to do it.

From the comments:

When you declare a variable with `extern`, you specify that it has external linkage, yes, but you only declare, and not define it. If you leave it without the `extern` keyword, it still has external linkage, but it's also a definition.

Comment: Okay, how if I just put a `int BOT_TIME;` in `constants.h` and nothing in `constants.cpp`. Now, there is just one definition, right?
Now the variable is defined like normal variables are defined in the main function. Why doesn't this work? Thank you

Comment: The default linkage is `extern` for non-const symbols and `static` /(internal) for const symbols.So *"Nope. How'd you figure?"* is Incorrect.

Comment: @Als are you saying `BOT_TIME` is `extern` by default? (if that's not what you're saying, your comment is confusing to the op)

Comment: @learner no it's not, because if you include the file in more places, they will all define that symbol.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Okay, But are you saying non-const variables are not `extern` by default? I've read that in many places.

Comment: I am saying `BOT_TIME` does have a external linkage by default.

Comment: @learner yes I am. `int x;` and `extern int x;` are not equivalent.

Comment: @Als not the same thing to what the op stated in the question. external linkage != variable declared with extern. Otherwise what'd be the difference?

Comment: @learner when you declare a variable with extern, you specify that it has external linkage, but you only declare it, not define it. If you leave it without the `extern` it still has external linkage, but it's also a definition.

Comment: Your last comment should be in the answer.

Comment: @Als good point, I think that's where the confusion came from - confusing linkage with declaration/definition.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I get it. Thank you. just extending, is  `static const int BOT_TIME` in `constants.h` a declaration and not a definition  ?

Comment: @learner that's a definition, but `static` gives internal linkeage. A copy of the symbol is created for each translation unit that defines the variable, so it's not really a global, but multiple copies.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, so in this case, it is totally fine to leave the `static out`, since it is by default static linkage and also a definition.

Comment: @learner `static` does something completely different. It creates a different copy for the variable everywhere where you use it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, but that is exactly what internal(static) linkage is, isn't it? code in that translation unit will be linked with an internal copy of the variable ,so each translation unit will end up having a copy.

Comment: @learner yes... (I meant it does something completely different than `extern`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable in a header file and define it once and only once in a source file.
The correct way to do this is:

**constants.h**

```
//declare the symbol as extern
extern int BOT_TIME;
```

**constants.cpp**

```
#include "constants.h"
//define the symbol once and only once
int BOT_TIME;
```

**XXXX.cpp**

```
#include "constants.h"

//Include the header file which declares it extern in any source file 
//you want to access it
//use BOT_TIME
```

You can declare a variable as many times but you can only define it once.
If you define a variable more than once you violate the **[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.

```
extern int BOT_TIME;
```

is a declaration and `#1` only makes the same declaration twice, this is allowed but it doesn't work since you never define the variable.Note that every `extern` variable must be defined once or the compiler cannot find its definition and hence complains.

In `#2` you define the same symbol multiple times in different translation units.This violates the One Definition rule and hence the linker reports the same.

`#3` is the correct way to do it.

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: `compiler cannot find its definition and hence complains`. Isn't it the linker that complains here? Now that I've declared it extern, the compiler will leave a place of that variable for the linker to fill. But the linker won't find it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @learner: Yes you are correct.It is the job of the linker to link the definition.I should have said *Implementation* or rather specifically Linker and not compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int x;     // declaration
int x;            // definition
extern int x = 3; // definition
```

In general, you need a declaration in the header file, for source files that need to know about `x`. You need **one** definition, in one source file, so that there is actually an object `x`.